# How to get product list and create product in fronend Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1

In magento 2, I want create page allow user create product and get list product be created by user. How to I can make it? Any suggestion? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Pls see here https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-programmatically-create-product/

Comment: Thanks @Abdul, There is a way get product list, because i want get product grid like in admin, i try use include `<uiComponent name="product_listing"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product" name="products_list"/>` in my block but it not success